# CoRD: How to set up a dynamic address

Tags: networking, mac, remote-desktop

I am using [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/) to connect my Mac to a PC on a home network.
A dynamic address is being assigned to my PC every time I switch the router on/off.
For example:
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.5
10.0.0.8

At the moment I have to reconfigure the ADDRESS field CoRD each time.
I would like to know if there is any way to avoid this inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assign your PC a static IP address within the subnet of your router. (Start -> Run -> ncpa.cpl -> select network adapter -> right click, properties -> IP Version 4 -> Properties -> and make the change there.)
- Use any DHCP reservation capability of your router to always give your computer's MAC address a given IP (different depending on type of router).
- See if you can enter the computer name in the field where it expects the IP address (not sure if it will work with CoRD but worth a shot)